# Separately excited DC generator as a constant current source

Tags: dc, current-source, generator

Is it possible to operate separately excited DC generator as a constant current source using the following method?

Keeping torque due to prime mover and field winding constant, reduce armature reaction close to zero using compensating windings and interpole windings.

Is this method practically possible and can it be implemented or is there some flaw in this method?

Comment: An ideal current source supplies a fixed current to any load. It develops whatever output voltage is necessary, from zero to infinity. A practical current source has a wide voltage range and provides whatever voltage is necessary within that range. That means that it becomes a voltage source at the limits of that range. Perhaps you have some other definition of a current source. The system you describe does not fit the above definition.

Comment: How much power are we talking about? It might be easier to use a DC-DC converter downstream of the generator, while the generator can be excited so as to provide a roughly constant-voltage source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back Torque in a DC generator is proportional to armature current x armature flux.

So if as you say you keep the flux constant Back Torque is proportional to armature current. So constant torque constant current.

The problem is that in order to maintain constant torque you are going to have to alter the speed of the generator. This involves a system which can measure the torque or current and an appropriate governor on the prime mover. The practicality of this depends on a number of factors the main one being the required output power range and the torque curve of the prime mover.

Most generators are designed to operate at one speed which corresponds with the optimum operating point of the prime mover.

As has been said in the comments it is probably simpler to implement some sort of electronic constant current source.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted your answer but for me it is very informative thanks! So it means we can operate DC generator as a current source but  only for small change in load ?

Comment: This is rapidly becoming a mechanical engineering question. The output range that you can get depends on the range where you can maintain constant torque with varying speed from your prime mover. That question would be better asked on a mechanical engineering site.